# Can $\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(h+x_0)-f(x_0)}{h}$ be written as $\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(x)-f(x-h)}{h}$ when $h=x−x_0$?

Tags: calculus, limits, tangent-line

Say that we have a function $f(x)=x^2$, and two distinct points $P(x_0,f(x_0))$ and $Q(x,f(x))$ on the curve $y=f(x)$; if we let $Q$ approach $P$, then the slope of the secant through $Q$ and $P$ will approach a limit, which is the slope of the tangent line at $P$:$$m_{tan}= \lim_{x\to x_0}\frac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{x-x_0}. . . . .(1)$$When $h=x-x_0$, then:$$m_{tan}= \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x_0+h)-f(x_0)}{h}. . . . .(2)$$I have tried to write $(1)$ as:$$\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(x)-f(x-h)}{h}. . . . .(3)$$ instead of $(2)$, but when I tried finding the limit I got a different answer than that of $(2)$.
So, what is the point here?

Comment: Let $h=x_0-x$ instead.

Comment: Also should the $x$ in $(3)$ be an $x_0$?

Comment: @Ahmed $h=x-x_0 \Rightarrow x=x_0+h$ and $x_0=x-h$

Comment: Some friendly advice: the question in the title does not make sense. In  order that people show interest in your question please try be careful with both the title and the full question.

Comment: Why do you think $(1)$ and $(3)$ to be same? There is no rule of limits which allows you to move from $(1)$ to $(3)$.

Comment: When you make a change of variables / substitution in limits, all the instances of old variable must be replaced by the new variable. In $(1)$ the variable is $x$. And if you substitute $x=x_0+h$ then $h$ is new variable and after substitution the variable $x$ should not be there. So $(1)$ to $(2)$ is fine, but not $(1)$ to $(3)$.